# UMP two sided tests for exponential families

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likelihood-ratio, exponential-family, neyman-pearson-lemma, optimal

Consider a random variable $X$ with density $$f(x : θ) = C(θ)e^{η(θ)T(x)}h(x), θ ∈ Θ$$.
Assume that $η(θ)$ is strictly increasing in $θ$ and that the family is full rank. Show that there will not be any UMP size $0<α<1$ test for $H_0 : θ = θ_0$ against $H_1 : θ \neq θ_0$.
$$$$My attempt to the solution is as follows : Let $\phi_0$ be a UMP test for testing $H_0 : θ = θ_0$ against $H_1 : θ \neq θ_0$. Fix $\theta_1>\theta_0$. Then $\phi_0$ is the MP test for testing $H_0 : θ = θ_0$ against $H_1 : θ = θ_1$. So by the uniqueness part of the N-P Lemma $\phi_0$ must satisfy $$\phi_0(x)= \begin{cases} 1 & f(x:\theta_1)>kf(x:\theta_0) \\ 0 & f(x:\theta_1)<kf(x:\theta_0) \end{cases}$$. As given family is an exponential family and hence has the same support so $k$ cannot be $0$ or $\infty$ otherwise it will violate the size condition. Now $$f(x:\theta_1)>kf(x:\theta_0) \iff C(θ_1)e^{η(θ_1)T(x)}h(x)>kC(θ_0)e^{η(θ_0)T(x)}h(x) \iff T(x)>\frac{1}{\eta(\theta_1)-\eta(\theta_0)}\text{log}(\frac{kC(\theta_0)}{C(\theta_1)})=c_1 \ \text{say}$$. Then we have $$\phi_0(x)= \begin{cases} 1 & T(x)>c_1 \\ 0 & T(x)<c_1 \end{cases}$$ But we know that a test of this form is UMP for testing $H_0 : θ \leq θ_0$ against $H_1 : θ > θ_0$ and it is a size $\alpha$ test but it minimizes power for all $\theta<\theta_0$ among all the tests $\phi'$ which satisfy $E_{\theta_0}[\phi'(X)]=\alpha$ and so it cannot be a UMP for the two sided test. $$$$Is My solution correct? Also my proof didn't require the condition that the family is full rank. so do we need that condition?